# Jade: "TypeError: path must be a string" with --watch, when saving .jade file

Tags: string, terminal, pug, typeerror, watch

I have jade watching my directory to auto compile the templates to html files.
I've entered the following into the command line: `jade --watch templates`.
This returns `rendered templates/index.html` and compiles the .jade file just fine at first. 
But when I attempt to save the .jade file again, it does not compile, and returns this error in the command line:

`TypeError: path must be a string
    at Object.fs.lstat (fs.js:675:11)
    at renderFile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/bin/jade.js:172:6)
    at StatWatcher.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/bin/jade.js:119:11)`

Not sure what "path" it's referring to. But in case it's the directory "templates", I've tried the same command with the directory in quotes.

Answer (score 5):

This is apparently only an issue with the current `jade` version, 1.8.2.  If you lock your dependency in your package.json to the previous version (like below), this issue goes away.

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "dependencies": {
    "jade": "1.8.1"
  }
}
```

I've gone ahead and submitted a new [github issue](https://github.com/jadejs/jade/issues/1795), so hopefully this will get resolved.

Comment: Thanks I uninstall it globally and install jade@1.8.1 and it works perfectly

Comment: This has now been fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/jadejs/jade/commit/abff32cd5f5f02df4724031c139003cf56a42c96) and should go out in the next release.

Answer (score 0):

Ive run into the same problem and unfortunately ive run into a real wall on finding any documentation on this

If you want to, i found an alternative which i find adequate:

Download the code from here: http://swarminglogic.com/jotting/2014_02_watchfile
Its a simple file watcher
Alias the code or whatever your preference is.

Run `watchfile test.jade jade ./ --out /tmp` in the right directory. This will run a jade compilation through watchfile every time your file changes.

Workaround i know but it works... Why does people always take for granted that you bundle everything when running node services? On searches for `jade html TypeError: path must be a string` i only come upon **Express.js** threads